# How to remove Python3.5 on Mac OSX10.13

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to remove Python 3.5 and access Python 3.11.2. Follows is the output when I attempt to do so:

```
OlympusII-2:Cellar johnyearsley$ python -V
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)
OlympusII-2:Cellar johnyearsley$ pip uninstall python
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: Skipping python as it is not installed.
OlympusII-2:Cellar johnyearsley$ pip uninstall python3
DEPRECATION: Python 3.5 reached the end of its life on September 13th, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.5 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 3.5 in January 2021. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
WARNING: Skipping python3 as it is not installed.
OlympusII-2:Cellar johnyearsley$ python3 -V
Python 3.11.2
```

Tried following the example in https://www.techjunkie.com/macos-uninstall-python3/

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to remove Python 3.5, other than that you want to use Python 3.11.2? If the answer is no, my recommendation is to not worry about Python 3.5 (i.e., leave it be, don't delete it, don't touch it) and use a Python environment management tool, such as [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), to dictate what Python you want to use.

Comment: Thank you, Fanchen, The original problem was, at least I thought so, was that Mkdocs was using python3.5 which didn't have the updated version of jinja2. However, I reinstalled Mkdocs with pip3 and that seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Fanchen, The original problem was, at least I thought so, was that Mkdocs was using python3.5 which didn't have the updated version of jinja2. However, I reinstalled Mkdocs with pip3 and that seemed to solve the problem. –
Whatcom Sasquatch